# How to output geoJSON file from mysql spatial table?

Tags: mysql, geojson

I have a mysql spatial database ('mydb1') of one table ('pk'), that i obtained from a point shapefile using ogr2ogr tool. one row of this 'pk' table, is like:

```
 OGR_FID   SHAPE       CODIF    Position_X   Position_Y    Nom   Status
 1     [GEOMETRY-25o]  PAC182854  398235.38    414569.24    G-31   Vert
```

I need to output the geoJSON file of this table. I downloaded geoPHP library and used MySQL to GeoJSON script which i adapted to my settings, like below:

```
<?php
/**
* Title:   MySQL to GeoJSON (Requires https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP)
* Notes:   Query a MySQL table or view and return the results in GeoJSON format, suitable for use in OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.
* Author:  Bryan R. McBride, GISP
* Contact: bryanmcbride.com
* GitHub:  https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON
*/

# Include required geoPHP library and define wkb_to_json function
include_once('geoPHP/geoPHP.inc');
function wkb_to_json($wkb) {
    $geom = geoPHP::load($wkb,'wkb');
    return $geom->out('json');
}

# Connect to MySQL database
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb1','root','admin');

# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a WKB element
$sql = 'SELECT *, AsWKB(SHAPE) AS wkb FROM pk';

# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    # Remove wkb and geometry fields from properties
    unset($properties['wkb']);
    unset($properties['SHAPE']);
    $feature = array(
         'type' => 'Feature',
         'geometry' => json_decode(wkb_to_json($row['wkb'])),
         'properties' => $properties
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$conn = NULL;
?>
```

But when i execute the code on the browser, i get totally a blank page. What's wrong should i fix to output my geoJSON file plz?

Comment: You need to do your own debugging, e.g. print out the raw output from the MySQL query, arrays, etc. Turn on php error handling. These will give you an idea where things may go south.

Comment: @Shadow Sorry, i didn't understant what u said. may you explain?

Comment: Do you have any background in php programming or do you just try to tailor a pre-written script to your needs without any php knowledge?

Comment: @Shadow We started, few days ago in class, studying php programming, so i have a little knowledge, this is why i come asking what i need in this forum. What i didn't get from your comment which i thank you for, is to turn on php error handling. Where can i do it?

Comment: Then you should know how to print out the raw results from the MySQL query, how to print out the contents of the array variables, and how to turn on php error logging.

Comment: @Shadow Can you show me briefly how plz?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/213303/115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the php logs for more information in case an error ocured. Make sure error reporting and display are enabled:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

if no error show up inspect the $geojson object easiest would be using

```
print_r($geojson);
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment. The fact the you cannot comment atm is not an excuse for posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: @user3798397 print_r($geojson); i get: Array(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [geometry] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => Point
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 397570.1496
                                    [1] => 420385.6726
                                )

                        )

Comment: [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [OGR_FID] => 1
                            [codif] => PK177000V1
                            [position_x] => 397570.149600
                            [position_y] => 420385.672600
                            [type] => poteau kilométrique
                        )

                ) I didn't get longitutde and latitude values. instead i get stdClass object.

Comment: If you run this snippet is it giving you a proper JSON? $y = Array();
$y['type'] = 'FeaureCollection';
$y['features'] = Array();
$y['features'][0]['type']='Feature';
$y['features'][0]['geometry']= new stdClass();
$y['features'][0]['geometry']->type ='point';
$y['features'][0]['geometry']->coordinates =Array('x','y');
print json_encode($y, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: @user3798397 Yes a proper JSON format, but without values yet.

Comment: can you verify if something is broken with the numbers... just replace "JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK" with "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT"